# Save an ArrayList, to read or edit later

Tags: android-studio, arraylist

I have one doubt. Maybe it's simple, but I'm a beginner in android programming, so I'm so sorry if it's so trivial.

My app has an ArrayList, but it use an class as type.

"ArrayList arrayList;"

Here, users must to can add a new item using an fragment created to this. Then, in the principal screen, it must to show the list to the user.

My doubt is how can I save this list and recover when I need, read it and show to the users. Of course, I also need to change the list (deleting, editing or adding items in this list), and saving again when something change.

I don't know if it's info enough, but if you need more info to could help me, just ask and I can tell you what you need.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you will be using some listview / recyclerview for showing the list. In that case, you need to set this as the data in adapter and call notifydatasetchanged. The array list object should be a member of the custom adapter class. Please add more information to your question

Comment: Yes, I use listview to showing, and I'm using notifydatasetchanged. It's not my problem. I need to save the list in the user's phone, cause it will be generated by the user. He will add the info that it needs, and the app must to save it and show it later.